# Angular 8 drag drop dragover dragleave events not firing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop file upload in angular 8, heavily inspired by [this article](https://medium.com/@mariemchabeni/angular-7-drag-and-drop-simple-file-uploadin-in-less-than-5-minutes-d57eb010c0dc), and [this one](https://gist.github.com/darrenmothersele/7afda13d858a156ce571510dd78b7624).

I cant get any of the drag events to fire.  I've checked that the `DragDropDirective` is imported by using `mouseenter` methods in the same directive, which launch correctly, i also see that style that i added is correctly applied.

I've been banging my head against this all day, what am i missing?

Edit: **This works with files from a Files explorer, but not with files from the desktop.  Using Ubuntu 19.**

```
// component.html
<section appDragDrop class="panel" id="dropzone-wrapper" (onFileDropped)="uploadFile($event)">
    <input type="file" #fileInput (change)="uploadFile($event.target.files)" accept=".json" hidden>
    <label for="dropzone">
        <span>
            drag and drop here.
        </span>
    </label>
</section>

import { Directive, Output, Input, EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDragDrop]'
})
export class DragDropDirective {
  el: ElementRef
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }

  // Working fine
  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    console.log('mouse entering')
  }
  
  // Working fine
  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    console.log('mouse leaving')
  }

  // --- Not working ---
  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) onDragOver(evt) {
    console.log('A')
  }

  // --- Not working ---
  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) public onDragLeave(evt) {
    console.log('B')
  }

  // --- Not working ---
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public ondrop(evt) {
    console.log('C')
  }
}
```

### NOTE

Drag and drop doesn't seem to work from screen to screen on linux, you need to test with files from the same screen.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have provided works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayht81?embed=1&file=src/app/drag-drop.directive.ts

[image]

### Drop event

Drop will not fire unless you prevent the default behavior on over:

```
@HostListener("dragover", ["$event"]) onDragOver(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  console.log("A");
}
```

Proof of work:

[image]

Comment: It's true that i tried with a file from my desktop, is this supposed to workn only with files from the file explorer?  Thanks for the help

Comment: Unfortunately, can confirm it does not work from the desktop. So this will require some research.

Comment: here is a much cleaner version of the above snippet - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-75tjrq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: this comment was the key! "Drop will not fire unless you prevent the default behavior on dropover". thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, but it works for me:

```
@HostListener("dragover", ["$event"]) onDragOver(event: any) {
  event.preventDefault()
}
@HostListener('drop', ['$event']) onDrop(event: any): boolean {
  console.log("drop", event)
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this issue is usually that you've set `preventDefault()` and or `stopPropagation()` elsewhere which is messing with these listeners everywhere on the page.

Here is my go-to directive:
Pay attention to `preventBodyDrop`.

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

// Angular Drag and Drop File
//
// Add this directive to an element to turn it into a dropzone
// for drag and drop of files.
// Example:
//
// <div dropzone (dropzone)="onDrop($event)"></div>
//
// Any files dropped onto the region are then
// returned as an array of file objects.
// Which in TypeScript is `Array<File>`

@Directive({
  selector: '[libDropzone]',
  standalone: true
})
export class DropZoneDirective {
  // The directive emits a `fileDrop` event
  // with the list of files dropped on the element
  // as a JS array of `File` objects.
  @Output('libDropzone') fileDrop = new EventEmitter<Array<File>>();

  // Disable dropping on the body of the document.
  // This prevents the browser from loading the dropped files
  // using it's default behaviour if the user misses the drop zone.
  // Set this input to false if you want the browser default behaviour.
  @Input() preventBodyDrop = true;

  // The `drop-zone-active` class is applied to the host
  // element when a drag is currently over the target.
  @HostBinding('class.dragging-over') draggingOver = false;
  @HostBinding('class.dropped') dropped = false;

  // default list of allowed file extensions
  @Input() allowedExts?: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']; // iOS HVEC?


  // DRAG AND DROP EVENTS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  onDrop(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.draggingOver = false;

    const { dataTransfer } = event;

    if (dataTransfer?.items) {
      const files: any[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
        // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
        // TODO: confirm supported image file type (allowedExts)
        // optionally allow allowedExts to override allowed extensions
        if (dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
          files.push(dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile());
        }
      }
      dataTransfer.items.clear();
      if (!!files?.length) this.fileDrop.emit(files);
    } else {
      const files = dataTransfer?.files;
      dataTransfer?.clearData();
      if (!!files?.length) this.fileDrop.emit(Array.from(files));
    }

    this.dropped = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dropped = false;
    }, 3000);
  }

  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
  onDragOver(event: DragEvent) {
    this.draggingOver = true;
  }

  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event'])
  onDragLeave(event: DragEvent) {
    this.draggingOver = false;
  }

  // disable native browser file drop on <body>
  @HostListener('body:dragover', ['$event'])
  onBodyDragOver(event: DragEvent) {
    if (this.preventBodyDrop) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('body:drop', ['$event'])
  onBodyDrop(event: DragEvent) {
    if (this.preventBodyDrop) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Drag and Drop event for file upload you should use `window:dragenter` event listener. This event starts file drag into window and when drag event started then `dragover`, `dragleave` and `drop` will work as well.
**Example:**

```js
// missing listener which detects that something was dragged into window area
@HostListener('window:dragenter', ['$event'])
onWindowDragEnter(event: any): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}

@HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
onDragOver(event: any): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ...
}

@HostListener('dragleave', ['$event'])
public onDragLeave(event: any): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ...
}

@HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
public onDrop(event: any): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ...
}
```

**However solution wasn't tested on Ubuntu**